# Angular 4 Universal "window is not defined"

Tags: angular, universal

My project was running perfectly but when i implement universal then i am getting "window is not defined".

My error is as below.

```
 node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js:2643

 })(window, document, 'Hammer');

      ^
  ReferenceError: window is not defined
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/resumeble_unv/node_modules/hammerjs  /hammer.js:2643:4) 

      at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
     at node_modules/ngx-carousel/bundles /ngxcarousel.umd.js:2:174
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ngx-carousel/bundles/ngxcarousel.umd.js:5:2)
```

package.json

```
  { 
  "name": "resumable-ang",

  "version": "0.0.0",

  "license": "MIT",

  "scripts": {
   "prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc",
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts" },

   "private": true,
  "dependencies": {

  "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^4.*",
  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
  "@ng-select/ng-select": "^0.12.0",
  "@ngx-share/core": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.2.15",
  "angular-progress-http": "^1.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5",
  "ngx-page-scroll": "^4.0.2",
  "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
  "ngx-sharebuttons": "^3.*",
  "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
  "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},

  "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
  "tslint": "~5.3.2",
 "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: you dont have hammerjs in your dependencies, did you run `npm install hammerjs --save`?

Comment: Actual Google is not crawling all except home page website

Comment: Thanks for quick comments @mast3rd3mon but i have used hammerJs

Comment: but it isnt in your dependencies, and it errors anyway, try getting the latest stable build using `npm install hammerjs --save`

Comment: Yes @mast3rd3mon was correct, try to install by `npm install`

Comment: @dinesh I have installed hammerJs and current version is "hammerjs": "^2.0.8"

Comment: sorry to said that because in Package.json page dependencies we can see the installed modules, there i doesnt see that, so only said. ok well can you see  `"hammerjs": "^2.0.8" ` in package.json page?

Comment: Installed hammerJs (hammerjs@2.0.8 ) but still getting same error
@mast3rd3mon

Comment: can you try to use this one? http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/

Comment: because, from my understand your module may included normal min js to your project so that only you can get the errors, you can see the last line of your error in minjs of Hammerjs https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js

Comment: @khurshedalam check above comment

Comment: Thanks for helping, I am installing "npm install --save angular-hammer"
and let you know @dinesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163855/discussion-between-dinesh-and-khurshed-alam).

Comment: Sure bro @dinesh

Answer (score 3):

As @trichetriche said. You don't have access to `window` object on the server side. The only thing which should be mentioned here is, that the better way instead of using

```
if(window) {}
```

Would be (let's say it is more "Angular" ;) ):

```
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {}

public someMethod(): boolean {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
         //action specific for browser
    }
}
```

You can take a look at live example in one of my repositories:
https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa/blob/master/src/app/services/notification.service.ts

Answer (score 1):

Because Angular Universal allows you to create server-side rendered pages. And in a server, you don't have a browser, therefore you don't have a window.

You should make a condition to test if the window exists, something like this

```
if (window) { /* do your window things here */}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @squadette/hammerjs instead of hammerjs.
 @squadette/hammerjs is server side render friendly.

To use it, just run

```
npm i @squadette/hammerjs
```

to instal it. then replace change

```
import  'hammerjs';
```

to

```
import  '@squadette/hammerjs';
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It seems the @squadette version is a much newer fork which does, indeed, check for availability of window and document before trying to use them, thus solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `npm i hammerjs`
2. Add to your `package.json` :

```json
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
"types": [
  "hammerjs",
  "jasmine",
  "jasminewd2",
  "node",
  "q",
  "selenium-webdriver"
]
```

3. add `import 'hammerjs';` to `main.ts` file

If you still have problems use:

- `npm --force`
- `npm install`