# Angular Universal with @ng-toolkit/universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Attempting to implement server side rendering using Angular Universal for an Angular 6 app.  Tried all the tutorials I could find, but could only get @ng-toolkit/universal to serve the app.  When I view the page source, it does not show a server side rendered app, it looks just like the normal angular app.

Are there extra steps I need to take with @ng-toolkit/universal to achieve server side rendering with angular universal?  The app is set up as a PWA as well.

UPDATE: The main reason for using ng-toolkit was the DOM Window mock class.  This app uses MDBootstrap which has a transitive dependency on HammerJS.  When attempting to run server side, I get the 'window is not defined' error for HammerJs.

Comment: that error is because you're (HammerJs) is trying to run client object in a server enviroment. Can you provide code of how you're implementing such PWA?.

Comment: @Yoarthur, I'll create a small app with the same problem and i'll send you the repo.

Comment: use https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 0):

You have to build for production before ng-toolkit changes will be visible in browser:

```
npm run build:server:prod
```

followed by

```
npm run server
```

*Note: "ng build --prod" throws an error on "npm run server" currently

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I just solve it. you can find my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59296224/8041124